# on dialog make background unclickable

Tags: jquery, dialog

Whenever i'm opening the jQuery dialog i want to be unable to select anything in #view

```
    $("#open-dialog").on("click",function(evt) {
        $("#dia-show").dialog({
            width: 195,
            position: {
            at: 'center',
            of: $('#view')
        },
            draggable: true,
            appendTo: "#view",
            modal:true
        });
            return false;
            parent().draggable({
            containment: '#view'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `modal` to true will enable background not clickable :

```
 $("#open-dialog").on("click",function(evt) {
        $("#dia-show").dialog({
            width: 195,
            position: {
            at: 'center',
            of: $('#view')
            modal:true
            draggable: true,
            appendTo: "#view",

        });
            return false;
            parent().draggable({
            containment: '#view'
        });
    });
```